# Suitable HTTP response for "not authorized" but without giving a WWW-Authenticate header

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest

I am writing a HTTP service. I want the status codes to distinguish between two states:

1. user is not logged-in
2. user is logged-in but may not perform a given action

It seems like `HTTP 403 Forbidden` obviously covers case #2, but for case #1 I am not sure. Reading the list it looks like `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` is suitable [but according to this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

> The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource.

My service cannot fulfil this requirement.

My service will be accessed from XMLHttpRequest in browser Javascript. Does it matter if I abuse the protocol and return 401 without `WWW-Authenticate`? Or is there a more suitable (standards-compliant) way for the service to say "you are not logged-in and I am not going to tell you how"?